# Ruby require gives error cannot load such file -- Kennel.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

The requires can't load the files given.
Any tips or help would be appreciated. thanks

```
require "Kennel.rb"
require "Animal.rb"


birdKennel = Kennel.new( "The Birdy Kennel" )

helloKitty = Animal.new( "Wolf" )
helloKitty.setColor( "Green" )
helloKitty.setName( "Misse" )

tom = Animal.new("Dog")
tom.setColor( "Orange" )
tom.setName( "Karto" )

birdKennel.addAnimal(helloKitty)
birdKennel.addAnimal(tom)

birdKennel.visit()
```

Comment: need to see the FS structure you are having..

Comment: Please improve the title of this question so that it's grammatical and readable.  Please include the stack trace in the body of the question, not the title.

Comment: sorry, i will do that next time, and thanks

Comment: In Ruby, it's idiomatic to use snake_case and *NOT* name variables and methods in CamelCase. For example, use: `bird_kennel`, `hello_kitty`, `set_color`, `set_name`, `add_animal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory was removed from the default LOAD_PATH in Ruby 1.9.2. You could do any of:

```
 require_relative 'Kennel' 

 require './Kennel' 

 LOAD_PATH << '.' 
 require 'Kennel'
```

Comment: $: is an alias for LOAD_PATH if you prefer shorter variable names

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may want `require_relative`, e..g.

```
require_relative "Kennel"
require_relative "Animal"
```

is the files are in the same directory.

Comment: yes C:\Users\BasharN\Documents\Ruby     both the files in that directory

Comment: is that where you are when you run the program?  Not that `require` is expecting an absolute path.  Looks like you're on Windows though perhaps which is not my domain.

Comment: I run the commnad like this with cmd   C:\Users\BasharN\Documents\Ruby>ruby main.rb

Comment: when i run the animal .rb  its run wthout problems , and the kennel1.rb runs without problems so its about the path